# iOS application's orientation remember?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have several view controllers, which maintains only landscape mode and one view controller with all interface orientations(for example, slideshow). "Splash screen" can only in landscape mode. After "slideshow" is in portrait mode and I fully terminate application(from task bar too), application starts a "splash screen"(what should in landscape mode) unexpectly in portrait. But why it happens, if splash screen is actually not rotates in portrait if device rotated? And how to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SplashScreenViewController write:-

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);

}
```

Comment: And there are is.  SplashScreen autorotates all time(after starting too) in landscape regardless device rotation(it's good), but if interface orientation of slideshow been portrait, and I terminate application or go back from slideshow(in portrait) to splashscreen, then splashscreen is not autorotates to landscape. Very strange

Comment: yes this strange thing happens .For overcoming this you need to set your device orientation.